# angularjs routing based on conditions case statements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a different requirement for my angularJS views. 
I have a cart running where an individual can checkout with 0$ as well ( some free gifts )
So, for the payment page view we came up with a different idea.

```
if($cart_total>0){
   show payment page view;
} else {
   show confirmation page view;
}
```

so how do I do the same in angularJS routing. My angular routing looks like this

```
as.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/index', {templateUrl: 'partials/index.html', controller: 'IndexListCtrl'})
            .when('/shop/:id', {templateUrl: 'partials/shop.html', controller: 'ShopCtrl'})
            .when('/payment/:id', {templateUrl: 'partials/payment.html', controller: 'PaymentCtrl'})
            .when('/confirm', {templateUrl: 'partials/confirm.html', controller: 'ConfirmCtrl'})
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/index'});

});
```

So I need to show payment view only when cart_total > 0 else show confirm view.

Please help !!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use [$route service events](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

PS. Here is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978248/angularjs-conditional-routing-in-app-config)

Answer (score 0):

First add a definition to your routes by declaring a constant like that.

```
 angular.module("App")
.constant('Cart', {
  showCart : 'true'
});
.when('/payment/:id',{
    templateUrl:'',
    access:Cart.showCart
})
```

Then you have to options. First in the run function check `'$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart'` event and inside it you can access the route by `var location = $location.path(); var route = $route.routes[location];`and then access the user role by route.access; then you can remove or add Html components.Or you can make a simple directives that dose the same route checking and use the link function to remove or add Html component